# Non-pipeable formatting characters

Tags: bash, shell, rhel

On my machine the command `mysql -e "show databases"` generates the following output:

```
$ mysql -e "show databases

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| database1          |
| database2          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

However, when I pipe this to any command (or redirect to file), the formatting vanishes:

```
$ mysql -e "show databases" | cat

Database
information_schema
database1
database2
mysql
performance_schema
sys
```

I thought that the formatting may come through stderr, but this does not seem to be the case:

```
$ mysql -e "show databases" 2>/dev/null

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| database1          |
| database2          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

Why do the formatting characters not go through the pipe? Can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL changes output [format] when the pipe changes from stdout to another application.

To preserve this format use the `--table` option or use `--tabbed` or `--vertical`.

Comment: Thank you! How can an application know if it gets piped to another application or a file?

Comment: @Flourid see [How does a program know if stdout is connected to a terminal or a pipe?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/515778)